# cannot solve ts error: object is possibly undefined error

Tags: typescript, tslint

My code is something like below and I keep getting 'object is possibly undefined' error with red lines under **telemetryData .get(cid)**. Not sure how to solve this issue? Thanks!

```
const updateLoadedCount = mutatorAction('updateLoadedCount', (cid: string) => {
    const telemetryData = getTelemetryStore()?.telemetryData;
    if (telemetryData?.has(cid)) {
        if (telemetryData .get(cid) !== undefined) {
            telemetryData .get(cid).imageLoaded =
                telemetryData .get(cid).imageLoaded + 1;
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign `telemtryData.get(cid)` to a value and then check if it is undefined (or nullish, or falsey).  TypeScript isn't going to know that some condition isn't going to change the result of `telemtryData.get(cid)` the next time it is called.

```
const updateLoadedCount = mutatorAction('updateLoadedCount', (cid: string) => {
    const telemetryData = getTelemetryStore()?.telemetryData;
    const cidValue = telemetryData?.get(cid);
    if (cidValue !== undefined) {
        cidValue.imageLoaded += 1;
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you! That is very helpful!